# I am not sure what the following is expecting for

Tags: java, class, methods

I am really appreciate for those who helps!!

Here is the question:
Consider a class MotorBoat that represents motorboats.  A motorboat has private attributes for:

- The capacity of the fuel tank
- The amount of fuel in the tank
- The amount of fuel in the tank
- The maximum speed of the boat
- The current speed of the boat
- The efficiency of the boat’s motor
- The distance traveled

The class has methods to:

- Change the speed of the boat
- Operate the boat for an amount of time at the current speed
- Refuel the boat with some amount of fuel
- Return the amount of fuel in the tank
- Return the distance traveled so far If the boat has efficiency e, the
  amount of fuel used when traveling at a speed s for time t is e x s2
  x t.  The distance traveled in that time is s x t.

And here is what I got by so far:

```
public class MotorBoat {

    //the capacity of the fuel tank
    private double capaity;
    //the amount of fuel in the tank
    private double amount;
    //the maximum speed of the boat
    private double maxSpeed;
    //the current speed of the boat
    private double curSpeed;
    //the efficiency of the boat's motor
    private double efficiency;
    //the distance traveled
    private double distance;



    //Change the speed of the boat
    public void changeSpeed(double newSpeed)
    {
        this.curSpeed = newSpeed;
    }
    //Operate the boat for an amount of time at the current speed
    public void operateAmount(double newAmount)
    {
        this.amount = newAmount;
    }

    //Refuel the boat with some amount of fuel
    //I don't get this one

    //Return the amount of fuel in the tank
    public double getAmount()
    {
        return amount;
    }
    //Return the distance traveled so far
    public double getDistance()
    {
        return distance;
    }

    //If the boat has efficiency e, the amount of fuel used when traveling at a speed s for time t is e x s2 x t.  The distance traveled in that time is s x t.

    public double amountUsed()
    {
        double amountUsed = this.efficiency*(this.curSpeed*this.curSpeed)*(this.getDistance()/this.curSpeed);
        return amountUsed();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MotorBoat boat = new MotorBoat();
        System.out.println("Current Speed: " + boat.curSpeed);

        boat.changeSpeed(200);
        System.out.println("Current Speed: " + boat.curSpeed);

        System.out.println("Fuel Amount: " + boat.getAmount()); 
        boat.operateAmount(2000);
        System.out.println("Fuel Amount: " + boat.getAmount()); 

        System.out.println("Distance Traveled: " + boat.getDistance()); 

        boat.amountUsed(); 
        System.out.println("Fuel Amount: " + boat.amountUsed()); 

    }

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Instead of dumping your entire homework assignment please show us what code you're having issues with and give details about that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a contructor, or setting all values before trying to get them or there will be null pointers

```
public MotorBoat(double a, double b, double c /* etc*/){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```

also returning amunt used needs to have the `()` removed in the `return` else you are refering to the function, not the temporary variable you created in the function

Finally you need to have getters and setters for all values that are private you wish to acces from outside the class, say on an instance of the class, and then use these functions when operating on the class in a non-class scope, say your static manin in this case

Next time you ask a question, please specify the error, and what you are looking for help with, there is nothing wrong with asking for help with homework per say, but there is unless you show you tried and provide a describtion of what you need help with

Comment: Thank you for explaining it!! I don't get the part that says to write a method to refuel the boat with some amount of fuel. Should I add it to the original amount and declare a new amount?

Comment: @CherylLiang i'm assuming that it is meant to be added to the amount the bout currently has (you add in fuel, you won't empty it first), also there is probally a part that should consume some fuel, for instance if the dinstance traveled is x, and the gass used for traveling x is y., then the gas should have y removed when adding the distance, and you should check that the distance can't be decreased, unless resetting the instance with some method (again this is an assumption, there is nothing that makes it 100% clear to me defined in the question, but assuming it is not time traveling) :)

Comment: @CherylLiang also if it answered the question please mark as accepted to help others should they have a similar issue finding the answer